# Using Custom function with apply to create multiple columns from a single column

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am using this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kamyababedi/qatar-airways) for a small project. Using the Route column from the dataset, I am trying to build 3 columns - From, To and Via.

I am currently using a custom function with regex to identify the groups and create the columns. Can you please point what is wrong with the way I am using the apply or the function is framed?

```
def travel_route(row):
# layover_patt = r"(?P<source>[^,]+)\s+to\s+(?P<destination>[^,]+)\s+via\s+(?P<layover>[^.]+)"
# direct_patt = r"(?P<source>[^,]+)\s+to\s+(?P<destination>[^,]+)"
text = row["Route"]
# text = row
if "via" in text:
    pattern = r"(?P<source>[^,]+)\s+to\s+(?P<destination>[^,]+)\s+via\s+(?P<layover>[^.]+)"
    source = match.group("source")
    destination = match.group("destination")
    layover = match.group("layover")
    return pd.Series({"From":source,
                      "To":destination,
                      "Via":layover})

else:
    pattern = r"(?P<source>[^,]+)\s+to\s+(?P<destination>[^,]+)"
    source = match.group("source")
    destination = match.group("destination")        

    return pd.Series({"From":source,
                      "To":destination,
                      "Via":np.nan})
```

# df_with_route.apply(travel_route,axis=1) 
df_with_route = df_with_route["Route"].apply(travel_route) 
#df_with_route.head()

# travel_route("Tokyo to London Heathrow via Doha")
# travel_route("Auckland to Doha")

Comment: read notice : [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.str.split`, which would be cleaner and more efficient than `apply`:

```
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"Route": ["Dubai to Gatwick via Doha", "Colombo to Doha"]})

# split on ' to ' or ' via '
df[["From", "To", "Via"]] = df["Route"].str.split(" to | via ", expand=True)
```

```
                       Route     From       To   Via
0  Dubai to Gatwick via Doha    Dubai  Gatwick  Doha
1            Colombo to Doha  Colombo     Doha  None
```